# Drilldown or Drill up dimension hierarchy, based on condition MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I have a user dimension, containing

1. Level1
2. Level2
3. Level3
4. Level4
5. Level5

This dimension has 2 hierarchies, one for the users - with all the properties combined, and also a user type hierarchy. What I want is when I create an MDX query, all the users OF A SPECIFIC TYPE are expanded.

I did create an MDX query, using the filter, as follows;

```
SELECT
{  
[Measures].[Measure] 
    } ON 0, non empty  { 
        FILTER (
            {[Dim User].[User Hierarchy].[Level1].allmembers  }
            ,[Dim User].[User Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Children.Count > 1
        ) 
    } ON 1

    from [cube]
```

However I would like to do the same, using maybe other functions OR maybe drill through action using a condition such as the following?

```
   [Dim User].[User Type Key].CurrentMember IS 
descendants([Dim User Type].[UserTypeIdHierarchy].&[9],0,self)
```

The user hierarchy is ragged. Are there MDX functions which make this easier?

Comment: What do you mean by "users OF A SPECIFIC TYPE"? How can the type of a member of the hierarchy be determined? What do you mean by "with all the properties combined"? Please note: We do not know your cube model, even if you are very familiar with it.

Comment: I have a hierarchy in the users dimension, which is UserTypeHierarchy. I want that if the current user element, is a descendant of a specific item in the UserTypeHierarchy, it would drill down. That is my objective.

Comment: What do you mean by "it would drill down"? What should be returned by the measure in order to "drill down"?

Comment: I would want on the Y axis, the hierarchy only of user type X expanded when loading the report

Comment: So you mean that - depending on the user executing the query - you want to have a different selection of the rows? How do you map the current user to the user hierarchy?